# Using SEGGER SystemView with STM32

Tags: debugging, stm32, segger-jlink

Currently I'm developing a project with FreeRTOS on a STM32L476VGT.
Until now I've been debugging with Ozone(SEGGER) and J-Link (Edu and Ultra+)

Now I would like to "debug" or record system event using SystemView (SEGGER), but it's not working.

first of all some of the configurations I think there are important:
16Mhz HSE --> internal 80Mhz SysClk
FreeRTOS V8.2.3

J-link (SCLK,SDIO & SWO connected)

Project created with cubeMx so ST HAl libraries are in use(I know that for many people is bloatware but is what it was when I get the project).

main.c

```c
#include "SEGGER_SYSVIEW.h"

//// -- includes, prototypes and definitions

void main (void){

    /// -- Hardware init

    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Init(1000, 80000000, 0, 0);
    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Start();

    /// - tasks creation
    osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
    defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);

    /* Start scheduler */
    osKernelStart();

}
```

I put only the basic lines of code that I have add to the project in order to use the SystemView.

under this lines I attache a screen capture of System Viewer.

[image]

EDIT 1:

I've created a new projet to tart from the beginning.

STM32L476RG yes R is another board with 3 leds
cubemx : STM32L4 lib 1.10.0
FreeRTOS V9.0.0

main.c

```c
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();

    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Init(1000, 80000000, 0, 0);
    SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Start();

    osThreadDef(defaultTask, StartDefaultTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
    defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(defaultTask), NULL);

    osThreadDef(ledControlTask, ledcontrol, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
    ledControlTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(ledControlTask), NULL);

    osKernelStart();

    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

```c
void ledcontrol(void const * argument)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,LED1_Pin);
        osDelay(500);
    }
}
```

Same result:

[image]

if I click STOP I get:

[image]

Also if I put as it's explain in SEGGER SystemView UM0802 pdf Manual:

```c
SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Init(1000, 80000000, 0, 0);
SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Start();
```

for:

```c
SEGGER_SYSVIEW_Conf();
```

I get same output

Many thanks,

Guillermo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, 
RFM(UM08027_SystemView.pdf)!!
I forgot to apply the freeRTOS patch file. 
There are some mismatches between the line in the patch and the line in the file.

Now works perfect.

[image]